# How to get total cart in Django?

Tags: django, function, e-commerce, cart, shopping-cart

I have 2 models: order and cart
this is the order's model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity=models.IntegerField(default=1)
    ordered=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ordered_date= models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
         return f'{self.product.name}({self.quantity})'
    def get_total(self):
        total=self.quantity * self.product.price
        return total
```

and this is the cart'model:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    orders=models.ManyToManyField(Order)
    
    def __str__(self):
         return self.user.username

    def get_total_cart(self):
        orderitem = self.orders.all()
        total = sum(item.get_total() for item in orderitem)
        return total
```

How could I fix the get_total_cart() function please

Comment: When you call ```get_total_cart``` what happens? Could you please describe the problem more clearly?

Comment: when i call get_total_cart nothing display on the screen